# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'popen2' (How can i install popen2?)

Tags: python-3.x, popen

I'm using python 3.6 and triying to import pyvb. But when i typed import pyvb, this error occured:

[no module named popen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G096A.png)

I couldn't find how to install "popen2". Instead, i did this: pip install popen. But it didn't work for me. How can i install popen2?

Answer (score 1):

This module has been [deprecated since version 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/popen2.html). You have to use `subprocess` module now. For migrating you can also use [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)